# Align multiple img in different divs

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I have 4 pictures that I wish to align, the issue I have is that they are not in the same div and I cannot find a responsive solution.

Depending on the size of the screen, the text may take up to 3 lines and I would like for all of the logos to adapt simultaneously even if their own text does not have as many lines.

This is what I currently have :

[image]

The logos are what I would like to align.

This is the HTML :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="buffer"></div>
      <p class="text-center">Mon LinkedIn</p>
      <a class="image-link" href="link1">
        <img class="image-link img-size" src="assets/img/contact/LinkedIn-Logo.png">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="buffer"></div>
      <p class="text-center">Mon profil Malt</p>
      <a class="image-link" href="link2">
        <img class="image-link img-size" src="assets/img/contact/logoMalt.png">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="buffer"></div>
      <p class="text-center">Mes projets open source</p>
      <a class="image-link" href="link3">
        <img class="image-link img-size" src="assets/img/contact/so-logo.png">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="buffer"></div>
      <p class="text-center">Mes contributions open source</p>
      <a class="image-link" href="link4">
        <img class="image-link img-size" src="assets/img/contact/GitHub_Logo.png">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS :

```
.image-link {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.img-size {
  max-width: 100px;
  max-height: 20px;
}

.buffer {
  padding-top: 40px;
}
```

I did try to put the text and the logos in different rows but even though it yields a good result on big screens, it does not on small screens ( the text gets separated of the logo )

Comment: A solution is to set the height of the text container (create a div around your <p> for that), above your image, to be constant on your four divs

Answer (score 0):

position your link at the bottom will do the trick for you

```
.image-link {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
}
```

and you can set the **max-height** for your text container if you want

Comment: it only partially works. It does get everything aligned but it is no longer centred in the div

Comment: the parent div is smaller than the logo. The image ends up in the bottom left corner and therefore not centred

Answer (score -1):

You can adjust the height of the text (paragraph tag) by auto. If don't help done it by changing auto to 20% - 40%, depending on the size of the screen. You have to check the maximum height but I think 30% would be sufficient according to the text.

```
.buffer p {
height = 30%
}
```